# Adding NSArray Index String to tableView Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Right now I'm passing an NSArray of names to a tableViewController;

```
NSArray *listOfNames = [@"Sally", @"Bob", @"Joe];
```

The listOfNames is passed in the segue. I'd like to set the title of each cell to the name of each person.

in cellForRowAtIndexPath, I'm trying

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"nameCell"
                         forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = self.listOfNames[indexPath.row]; //????
```

All I want to do is just take the string from the array and put it as the title of the cell. What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: What's not working about your current approach?

Comment: Hmm, from NSLog it seems that the cellForRowAtIndexPath method isn't being called. I set up the rows based on the array.count. Do I have to do anything special in viewDidLoad? @dasblinkenlight

Comment: check if you set the delegate and datasource of your tableview to your class where you implement "cellForRowAtIndexPath"

Comment: `viewDidLoad` happens too early. You should force a refresh of the table in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: looks like I didn't correctly link the property between the tableView and .m file. works now. thanks for your help!